# Compare arrays of different lengths in Postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, comparison

I am using Postgresql to store Ruby gem version numbers. I would like to filter these versions on custom predicates and base versions provided by the user, and for that I am converting both versions to arrays of integers (for easier comparison): `4.2.0` becomes `'{4,2,0}'`.

This works fine:

```
'{4,0,0}' < '{4,1,0}' # yields TRUE
```

Still, I am having issues when array lengths are different:

```
'{4}' < '{5,0,0}' # yields TRUE
'{4,1,2}' < '{4,1}' # also yields TRUE when it should be FALSE
```

I couldn't find anything related to this specific issue in the documentation. How can I achieve what I am after? Would be great if the array with fewer elements would get right padded with zeros (that would lead to my expected behaviour).

Comment: Not sure what you means by "array", but `select '{4,1,2}'::int[] < '{4,1}'::int[];` yields `FALSE`...

Comment: Oh my, I'm surely tired. Thanks for pointing this out! You can add an answer for it.

Comment: Lets think that it is just a typo :o) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to standardize the array length for all versions such that when you make the array conversion`'{4,1}'` is `'{4,1,0}'`.
You can check the number of elements in each array after conversion using `array_length(array,dimension)` (in this case `dimension` is 1) and then append 
 using `array_append(array, element)` (in this case, `element` is 0) one or two zeros depending on the returned value.

Then when you make the comparisons:
`'{4,0,0}' < '{5,0,0}' # will still yield TRUE
'{4,1,2}' < '{4,1,0}' # will now correctly yield FALSE`

EDIT: as commented below, this is only the case where each element of the original array consists of a single digit integer or numeric character. Since the entire string is being compared, if the numeric elements of the string are more than a single characters in length, it could fail.

Comment: But `select '{40,1,2}' < '{4,1,0}';` yields `TRUE` :o)

Comment: `{1,2,3}` have no any relation to integers actually, it is just the string with some content. Obviously that OP and you also still trying to compare two strings instead of two arrays... (Hint: see my comment under the question)

Comment: I was only considering the case where each element of the original array consists of a single digit integer or numeric character. Since the entire string is being compared, if the numeric elements of the string are more than a single character in length, it could fail as @Abelisto has noted.